# Alterar nome do link com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Realizei algumas pesquisas e não sei se isto é possível.

No caso o que eu estou querendo fazer é o seguinte: Com jQuery gostaria de alterar o nome do link, assim:

Está assim:

```
<a href="checkout-review" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%;">Escolha uma opção de Frete</a>
```

E após um evento de `onChange()` ir para:

```
<a href="checkout-review" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%;">Finalizar Pedido</a>
```

> Notem que o que eu preciso alterar está `<a>AQUI</a>`

Como conseguiria fazer isto? Desde já obrigado

Comment: @LeAndrade não resolveu meu problema, já tinha visto essa pergunta antes.

Comment: Talvez esse link te ajude https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp

Comment: Estranho, pq a resposta está lá, é só fazer **`$("a").attr("href", "http://www.outra.coisa/")`**;

Comment: @LeAndrade no caso o exemplo acima ele está mudando o href. E eu precisa mudar apenas o texto. Conforme resposta abaixo! Mas agradeço a atenção. Obrigado

Comment: A ta blza, entendi errado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, você pode colocar um id no link e alterar a propriedade text.
Segue exemplo abaixo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>
<a href="checkout-review" id="link1" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%;">Escolha uma opção de Frete</a>
<button id="change" >Mudar texto</button>
<body>
    <script>
        $('#change').click(function(){
            $("#link1").text("Finalizar Pedido");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

No seu caso só não vai precisar utilizar o botão para mudar, mas aí você pode colocar no evento que quiser.

Comment: Obrigado é isto mesmo que eu preciso. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Há algumas maneiras de se fazer isso.

Se você tem controle da geração do link, então você pode fazer usando um span:

```
<a href="checkout-review" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%;"><span>Escolha uma opção de Frete</span></a> 

$('a span').html( 'Finalizar Pedido' );
```

Agora se você não tem controle do link gerado, então:

```
$("a").html($("a").html().replace("Escolha uma opção de Frete", "Finalizar Pedido"));
```